# bertTokenizer | ValueError: Connection error

Tags: python, bert-language-model, kaggle

trying to run the follwing code in kaggle:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
bert_model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(bert_model_name, do_lower_case=True)
```

and getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.
```

Answer (score 0):

[turn on the internet from the settings it worked for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhR6Y.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).